# Column Name Character Limit in MemSQL

Tags: singlestore

I have a data load job(spark connector) to MemSQL and it is failing due to the reason that the length of the column name is exceeding the permissible limit. Is there a way to fix this? I can not change the column names as they are programatically generated and I have no control on that.

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Identifier name '10000_BREAKING_BAD_IS_WAY_BETTER_THAN_THE_GAME_OF_THRONES_10000_LOWER_TOLERANCE' is too long
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1549)
    at com.memsql.spark.connector.DataFrameFunctions.createMemSQLTableFromSchema(DataFrameFunctions.scala:169)
    at com.memsql.spark.connector.DataFrameFunctions.createMemSQLTableAs(DataFrameFunctions.scala:104)
    at com.rb.pal.dm.MemSQLWriter$.main(MemSQLWriter.scala:65)
    at com.rb.pal.dm.MemSQLWriter.main(MemSQLWriter.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Is there a configuration setting which I can use to allow more characters for column names?

I am loading the data directly from parquet files into the MemSQL table

```
df.createMemSQLTableAs(dbName, tableName, dbHost, dbPort, user, password, useKeylessShardedOptimization = true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is not an available configuration for this issue as of the time of this answer.

If possible, try configuring the length at the query generator level.

Comment: How about using a JSON column? Will this still throw an error?
Does createMemSQLTableAs has a construct that supports JSON column?

Comment: If you mean using a key in a JSON column that is longer than the 64 character column name limit, the yes, that is permitted. If you want to add that column to your table creation your function call, you should use the extraCols param and specify type as JSON.